# Grounding in a balanced audio (XLR/Sub-D) switch?

Tags: switches, audio, ground, grounding

I am currently working on a switch for XLR/Sub-D connections. However I am unsure as to how I have to handle grounding. Do I have to switch the ground for each channel or can they be bundled together?

My Sub-D connector has a [TASCAM Pinout](https://support.antelopeaudio.com/en/support/solutions/articles/42000017434-type-of-screws-used-for-the-d-sub-connectors-and-pinout-standard), can those Grounds be tied together?

Otherwise I would assume that I simply switch each bundle of P/N/G directly to each XLR connector, however it would save an immense amount of PCB space/parts costs if I was to simply connect grounds together.

Comment: The question is, are they are all the same ground or a different ground?

Comment: @Justme The XLR connectors obviously go to different devices, the Sub-D is kind of a black box since it may be connected to a single device (e.g. tape machine) or another XLR Breakout.

Edit: Of course I don't know what exactly happens with the GND at the other end of the cable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can group all those grounds together and the system will likely work, however, if a long cable, that isn't connected to anything at the other end, is connected to an unused channel, then by permanently connecting the GNDs together, you've effectively added an aerial to the GND, potentially creating noise. Or if it's connected to an un-powered device, you could get similar noise problems, and those are just two examples off the top of my head.

You may be familiar with ground loops, or perhaps the ground lift switch common on DI boxes that pertain to the sort of noise problems that can be created in audio systems. Unfortunately, the correct wiring is usually application-specific, you should consider what you're planning to use the project for and add any suitable strategies. The engineering task is to weigh the cost and effort now, against the potential issues in use. I'd encourage you to ask another question with far more detail on what you're doing, and I'm sure you could get detailed answers in response.

Answer (score 0):

Well like you say, anyone can use the D-connector for any purpose, like linking two XLR to D-connectors together.

So the D-connector interface is actually irrelevant, you can ask the same question about grounding if you just have a switch box with XLR connectors directly.

If you have four devices A, B, C and D, and if you only want to connect devices A and B independently, and devices C and D independently, then it may not be a good idea to connect the grounds together on any connector.

But you also can do it and don't have to switch the ground if you don't want to, but then your device does not keep each XLR as a separate isolated connection.